# PayPal Express Checkout CREATE_PAYMENT_URL

Tags: javascript, paypal

When we use the checkout.js for the Express Checkout button, I'm not exactly sure what the CREATE_PAYMENT_URL is supposed to be?

Is that supposed to be our sandbox.paypal.com website?

I hit the Express Checkout button on my website, and I keep getting 404 errors, saying that whatever URL (I know, not the '' that is currently there) I put as the CREATE_PAYMENT_URL cannot be found as a resource.

```
                var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = '';
                var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '';

                paypal.Button.render({
                    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',
                    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

                    payment: function(resolve, reject) {
                        return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function (data) {
                            resolve(data.paymentID);
                        })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            });
                    },
                    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                        return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                            paymentID: data.paymentID,
                            payerID: data.payerID
                        }).then(function () {

                            // The payment is complete!
                            // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
                        });
                   }

                }, '#paypal-button');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your server to create a payment id, and pass it back to the client-side script: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/create-express-checkout-payments/